# SMO not copying role memberships

Tags: c#, sql, database, smo

Hello I'm trying to use SMO to create an exact copy of one DB in the same server. I'm able to copy the schema, the data and the users, but I just noticed that the roles for the users are not copied between the databases. Their roles look like this:

Original DB

[image: Original DB]

Cloned DB

[image: Cloned DB]

My current transfer object configuration looks like this:

```
Transfer t = new Transfer(database);
t.Options.DriAll = true;
t.CopySchema = true;
t.CopyData = true;
t.CopyAllDatabaseScopedCredentials = true;
t.CopyAllRoles = true;
t.CopyAllUsers = true;
t.PreserveDbo = true;
t.PreserveLogins = true;
t.DestinationServer = connection.DataSource;
t.DestinationDatabase = dbname;
t.TransferData();
```

But the roles are not copied, and because of that, when the user tries to read/write anything I get the 'Log in failed' error for that user, is there a config that I'm missing? Or is this not possible using SMO?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have the same issue, do you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `t.Options.IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = true`